# Why Can't I call this method?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, object, methods

I'm trying to call a method from another class within a service, however it's saying that the method I'm trying to call doesn't exist and would like some help if possible.

the program is a work project, which logs user inactivity as we've had issues with people not picking up the phone, code is below, this is a topshelf service that consumes messages from rabbitMQ and I want it to consume the messages and forward them to a database =]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NLog;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
using Topshelf;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using EasyNetQ;
using RabbitMQ;
using EasyNetQ.Topology;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AccessEye;

namespace LogService
{

    public class WindowsServiceHost : ServiceControl, ServiceShutdown
    {
        public static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();


        public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
        {

            Program.bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=as01.access.local;virtualHost=DEV-Reece;username=reece;password=reece").Advanced;

            //var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=as01.access.local;virtualHost=DEV-Reece;username=reece;password=reece").Advanced;
            var queue = Queue.Declare(true, false, true, null);
            var exchange = Exchange.DeclareFanout("UserActivityFanout", true, false, null);
            var exchangeTopic = Exchange.DeclareTopic("UserActivity", true, false, null);
            queue.BindTo(exchange, "#");
            exchange.BindTo(exchangeTopic, "#");
            Program.bus.Subscribe<AccessEye.LogData>(queue, (msg, messageRecInfo) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                WriteLogDataToDb();
                Console.WriteLine(msg.Body.UserName + " -- " + msg.Body.ComputerName + " -- " + msg.Body.EventType + " -- " + msg.Body.TeamviewerId);
            }));

            return true;

        }
```

And this is the method I'm trying to call

```
 public partial class AppForm : Form
    {

        public static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private Screensaver watcher;
        public Inactivity inactivity;
        IAdvancedBus bus;
        IExchange exchange;

    public void WriteLogDataToDb(LogData data)
            {
                using (var db = new LogService.UserActivityDataContext())
                {
                    DbLogData logData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LogData, DbLogData>(data);

                    int t = (int)data.EventType;

                    EventType eventType = db.EventTypes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == t);

                    if (eventType == null)
                    {
                        eventType = db.EventTypes.Add(new EventType
                        {
                            Event = GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(data.EventType),
                            Id = (int)data.EventType
                        });
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    logData.EventTypeId = eventType.Id;
                    db.LogEvents.Add(logData);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    }

    }
```

Comment: What is the class containing the method `WriteLogDataToDb`?

Comment: shouldn't you provide a parameter?

Comment: Passing it a parameter won't help if the function isn't declared inside `WindowsServiceHost` but instead another class like OP said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class with the `WriteLogDataToDb()` declared is called `ClassA`, then do two things.  Make the method `static`, and you actually have to pass some `LogData` data through it.

```
public class AppForm
{
    public static void WriteLogDataToDb(LogData data)
    {
        using (var db = new LogService.UserActivityDataContext())
        {
            DbLogData logData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LogData, DbLogData>(data);

            int t = (int)data.EventType;

            EventType eventType = db.EventTypes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == t);

            if (eventType == null)
            {
                eventType = db.EventTypes.Add(new EventType
                {
                    Event = GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(data.EventType),
                    Id = (int)data.EventType
                });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            logData.EventTypeId = eventType.Id;
            db.LogEvents.Add(logData);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Start` code, you have to call `AppForm.WriteLogDataToDb(data)`

**Edit:**

Now that these classes are in two different projects, you need to add reference so your `WindowsServiceHost` can use `AppForm`.  To do this:

1. Right-click > Properties on the project containing `AppForm`.  On the Application tab, take note of the `Assembly name:`
2. Right-click the References item in `WindowsServiceHost` and choose `Add reference`
3. Go to the `Projects` tab
4. Add the `Assembly name:` noted in step #1
5. Right click `AppForm` in `WindowsSerivceHost` and `Resolve` by adding your using statement.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the class containing that method, however when I call `AppForm.WriteLogDataToDb();` it says the name "Appform" doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: Is this all in one project?  When you right-click, can you `Resolve`

Comment: No it won't let me Resolve, I forgot to mention this but these are in the same solution, but they are different projects

Comment: You need to reference the project containing `AppForm` in the project containing `WindowsServiceHost`.

Comment: I've tried that but it says "A reference to "UserActivityMontor" Could not be added. Adding this project As a Reference would cause a circular dependency"

Comment: Okay, so you may needed to reconsider the design of your projects.  You can't have two projects reference each other.  You may need to move them into one project or add another.

Comment: I see! thanks for that, I may have to move them into another project then =]